# If statement not working with space character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, if-statement

I'm using some IFs which are working quite odd. It seems that xcode can only read them if there's no SPACE character. If there's, it doesn't read them. Here's my code. It works right for the first 2, but the last doesn't.

Any clue??

Thanks a lot!

```
if (txtParametro1EQQP.text == @"Adulto") {
    pvObjetivoAdultoEQQP.alpha = 1;
    pvPacienteEQQP.alpha = 0;
    pvObjetivoCriancaEQQP.alpha = 0;
    pvObjetivoAdultoDialiseEQQP.alpha = 0;
}else if (txtParametro1EQQP.text == @"Criança"){
    pvObjetivoCriancaEQQP.alpha = 1;
    pvPacienteEQQP.alpha = 0;
    pvObjetivoAdultoEQQP.alpha = 0;
    pvObjetivoAdultoDialiseEQQP.alpha = 0;
}else if (txtParametro1EQQP.text == @"Adulto em diálise"){
    pvObjetivoAdultoDialiseEQQP.alpha = 1;
    pvPacienteEQQP.alpha = 0;
    pvObjetivoAdultoEQQP.alpha = 0;
    pvObjetivoCriancaEQQP.alpha = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: for string comparison use the `-isEqualToString:` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `[myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Whatever string"]` in order to do string comparison in Cocoa.

Comment: Not just in Cocoa. If you do use `==` you're comparing pointers, not values stored in memory. Stick with `isEqualToString` as @Alladinian pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any problem in your code , problem with `txtParametro1EQQP's` text and the text you are comparing,

Text you are comparing = Adulto em diálise

Text in txtParametro1EQQP =  Adulto em dialise

There is difference in **á** and **a**

So just check value in `txtParametro1EQQP`